# Subtracting a nullable decimal null from value

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, decimal, nullable

I have come across a strange behavior with nullable decimals in C# today.

Subtracting a null value from some value gives null.

Example:

> 2300.00 - null = null :(

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal? a=2300.00m;
        decimal? b=null;

        var result=a-b;

        Console.WriteLine("Result is {0}",result);
    }
}
```

Why I am getting null instead of 2300?

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4dduI3)

Comment: If a value is nullable, shouldn't you be doing a null check?

Comment: 2300 - ihavenoidea == ihavenoidea, the only sensible behavior.

Comment: This is similar to calculations with doubles when one term is `Double.NaN`

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted, even if it does have a fairly obvious answer...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I would guess because it's a duplicate that a two second search would have answered...

Comment: @Equalsk Like so many questions, but the correct response there is to close it as a duplicate. The question itself is fine.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That's exactly what I did :-)

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is in line with `null`'s meaning of "unknown value": when you subtract an unknown value from 2300, you get an unknown value back.

If you want `null`s in your nullable to be treated as if they were zero, use null coalesce operator:

```
var result=(a ?? 0) - (b ?? 0);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/oBgpDz)

Answer (score 3):

Null is not a number. It is an unknown value. Six apples minus "an unknown" equals how many? It equals "an unknown amount."

Answer (score 2):

Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators):

> The predefined unary and binary operators or any overloaded operators
> that are supported by a value type `T` are also supported by the
> corresponding nullable value type `T?`. These operators, also known as
> *lifted operators*, produce `null` if one or both operands are `null`;

So, it's by design. All operations with null will produce null value.